# S'interposer entre / devant

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

Un groupe A lance des regards hostiles à une personne B.

> Je m'interpose **entre** eux.
>
> Je m'interpose **devant** le groupe A.

Est-ce que *s'interposer devant* est aussi correct ?

Comment: @Lambie *Entreposer* ≠ *Interposer*

Comment: Je me suis interposé [typo before entre une personne et un groupe.

Answer (score 1):

Cette combinaison est plus rare, mais n'est pas incorrecte.

Au contraire, *devant* est bien indiqué ici car on comprend que tu t'interposes entre le groupe A et la personne B, mais il est surtout clair que tu fais face au groupe A.

Quelques exemples où *devant* est utilisé après *s'interposer* :

> Barcelone - PSG : Navas s'interpose devant Griezmann ([BFM](https://rmcsport.bfmtv.com/football/ligue-des-champions/barcelone-psg-navas-s-interpose-devant-griezmann_VN-202102160457.html))

> Cette habitante de Los Angeles s'interpose devant un ours pour sauver ses chiens ([Huffingtonpost](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/entry/cette-femme-intervient-entre-un-ours-et-son-chien-qui-se-battaient-dans-son-jardin_fr_60b75445e4b0fd4b8693dcad))

> Il s’interpose devant les cambrioleurs ([Le journal de Saône-et-Loire](https://www.lejsl.com/edition-de-macon/2013/11/30/il-s-interpose-devant-les-cambrioleurs))

Comment: Ce n'est pas rare, c'est un sens différent. On s'interpose entre deux personnes/groupes quand les deux partis sont belliqueux (Le policer s'est interposé entre les deux groupes de jeunes qui s'affrontaient).  On s'interpose devant quelqu'un ou quelque chose quand un seul des deux partis est belliqueux et qu'on veut l'arrêter ([Emil Gallo](https://iconicphotos.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/1227921189a2xplrl-jpg.jpeg) s'est interposé devant le char soviétique). Et devant conviendrait dans le cas décrit par le PO.

Comment: Le titre dit: Barcelone - PSG : Navas s'interpose devant Griezmann
La PSG a déjà eu très chaud. **Keylor Navas s'est employé pour sauver les siens en s'interposant devant Antoine Griezmann.** Donc, il s'est entreposé entre les jouers de Seville et Griezmann.

Comment: @None Oui, c'est bien le sens que je donne aussi à cette phrase. J'ai écrit que c'était rare car *entre* est ce qui suit le plus souvent *s'interposer*, mais *devant* convient tout à fait dans le cas de la phrase d'Oreste, comme dans les phrases que je donne en exemple Le parti belliqueux, ou du moins contre lequel on a choisi le camp, est celui auquel on fait face.

Comment: @Lambie Non, Navas s'est interposé avec ses jambes entre le ballon tiré par Griezmann et le but qu'il gardait. C'était à la 14e minute du match. Il n'y avait pas de joueur de Barcelone ou de Paris derrière Navas, et encore moins de Séville puisque cette équipe n'a pas de raison de participer à un match Barça-PSG.

Comment: Oui, je pensais à l'autre Navas. En tout cas, il y a trois éléments.

Comment: @Lambie Bien sûr, par définition, il y a trois éléments en jeu dans une interposition. Un seul de ces éléments, le sujet, a besoin d'être exprimé quand on utilise le verbe s'interposer, les deux autres peuvent être implicites